# Apache Beam Deploying on DataFlow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, maven-3, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Hi I have created an apache beam pipeline, tested it and ran it from inside eclipse, both locally and using dataflow runner. I can see in eclipse console that the pipeline is running I also see the details, i. e. logs on the console.

Now, how do I deploy this pipeline to GCP, so that it keeps working irrespective of the state of my machine. For e.g., if I run it using mvn compile exec:java the console shows it is running, but i can not find the job using the dataflow UI.

Also, what will happen if I kill the process locally, will the job on the GCP infrastructure also be stopped?  How Do I know a job has been triggered independent of my machine`s state on the GCP infrastructure?

The maven compile exec:java with arguments output is as follows,

```
 SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    SLF4J: Found binding in 
    [jar:file:/C:/Users/ThakurG/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-
    jdk14/1.7.14/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.14.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/ThakurG/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-nop/1.7.25/slf4j-nop-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory]
    Jan 08, 2018 5:33:22 PM com.trial.apps.gcp.df.ReceiveAndPersistToBQ main
    INFO: starting the process...
    Jan 08, 2018 5:33:25 PM com.trial.apps.gcp.df.ReceiveAndPersistToBQ 
   createStream
    INFO: pipeline created::Pipeline#73387971
    Jan 08, 2018 5:33:27 PM com.trial.apps.gcp.df.ReceiveAndPersistToBQ main
    INFO: pie crated::Pipeline#73387971
    Jan 08, 2018 5:54:57 PM com.trial.apps.gcp.df.ReceiveAndPersistToBQ$1 apply
    INFO: Message received::1884408,16/09/2017,A,2007156,CLARK RUBBER FRANCHISING PTY LTD,A ,5075,6,Y,296,40467910,-34.868095,138.683535,66 SILKES RD,,,PARADISE,5075,0,7.4,5.6,18/09/2017 2:09,0.22
    Jan 08, 2018 5:54:57 PM com.trial.apps.gcp.df.ReceiveAndPersistToBQ$1 apply
    INFO: Payload from msg::1884408,16/09/2017,A,2007156,CLARK RUBBER FRANCHISING PTY LTD,A ,5075,6,Y,296,40467910,-34.868095,138.683535,66 SILKES RD,,,PARADISE,5075,0,7.4,5.6,18/09/2017 2:09,0.22
    Jan 08, 2018 5:54:57 PM com.trial.apps.gcp.df.ReceiveAndPersistToBQ$1 apply
```

This is the maven command I`m using from cmd prompt,

```
`mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.trial.apps.gcp.df.ReceiveAndPersistToBQ -Dexec.args="--project=analyticspoc-XXX --stagingLocation=gs://analytics_poc_staging --runner=DataflowRunner --streaming=true"`
```

This is the piece of code I`m using to create the pipeline and set the options on the same.

```java
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();

DataflowPipelineOptions dfOptions = options.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
dfOptions.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
dfOptions.setJobName("gcpgteclipse");
dfOptions.setStreaming(true);

// Then create the pipeline.
Pipeline pipeL = Pipeline.create(dfOptions);
```

Comment: I can see the logs on the console, it is a streaming job hence, I can`t wait for it to finish. Also I ran it using DataFlowRunner in eclipse configurations, after choosing a specific bucket and project and everything. I do not see the msg below, regarding the monitoring link.

Comment: Please include the relevant part of output of mvn compile exec:java from which you infer that "the console shows it is running".

Comment: @jkff added the output, the pipeline gets processed because, I can see the msgs ending up in BQ, where I`m expecting them to go. It is a streaming pipeline which reads msgs of pubsub, makes some API calls to enrich data and puts it in BQ.

Comment: Hmm, all of these log messages are from your code rather than from the Dataflow runner. Are you sure you're using the Dataflow runner rather than the Direct runner? - how are you configuring the runner, can you show the relevant part of code?... Alternatively could it be that your slf4j logging misconfigured and is displaying only your package's messages and dropping everything else?

Comment: @jkff , I`m selecting DataFlowRunner when run the program in eclipse from the RunConfiguration options, selecting the project and bucket and other stuff.

Comment: But you say it's working fine from eclipse. How are you specifying Dataflow runner when running using Maven?

Comment: @jkff apologies for the ambiguity, i mean functionally it does what i expect it to do, but I do not see it in google cloud console, neither do I see the log with the jobid that you mentioned in your answer. Added the maven command in the question, couldnt format it here clearly.

Comment: If your main program is printing logs about receiving message payloads, it seems that it's using the direct runner. Maybe your command line arguments are not being propagated? Can you show the code of how you set up your PipelineOptions and create the Pipeline object?

Comment: @jkff adding the code above where i`m adding pipeline options

Comment: It seems that you're invoking your program with some command-line arguments, but not passing these arguments to PipelineOptionsFactory.create(), so they are ignored. That might be the root of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you clarify what exactly do you mean by "console shows it is running" and by "can not find the job using Dataflow UI"?

If your program's output prints the message:

```
To access the Dataflow monitoring console, please navigate to https://console.developers.google.com/project/.../dataflow/job/....
```

Then your job is running on the Dataflow service. Once it's running, killing the main program will not stop the job - all the main program does is periodically poll the Dataflow service for the status of the job and new log messages. Following the printed link should take you to the Dataflow UI.

If this message is not printed, then perhaps your program is getting stuck somewhere before actually starting the Dataflow job. If you include your program's output, that will help debugging.

Comment: I finally figured it out. If i provide the options at the time of creation and just call pipeline.run() , it does not pick pick up the options. Although, If i supply the options as argument to run method, i.e. pipeline.run(dataflowOptions) , then it works and runs on the gcp, I can see the log that you mentioned. This looks to be different from the documented behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

To deploy a pipeline to be executed by Dataflow, you specify the `runner` and `project` execution parameters through the command line or via the `DataflowPipelineOptions` class. `runner` must be set to `DataflowRunner` (Apache Beam 2.x.x) and `project` is set to your GCP project ID. See [Specifying Execution Parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params). If you do not see the job in the Dataflow Jobs UI list, then it is definitely not running in Dataflow.

If you kill the process that deploys a job to Dataflow, then the job will continue to run in Dataflow. It will not be stopped.

This is trivial, but to be absolutely clear, you must call `run()` on the `Pipeline` object in order for it to be executed (and therefore deployed to Dataflow). The return value of `run()` is a `PipelineResult` object which contains various methods for determining the status of a job. For example, you can call `pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();` to force your program to block execution until the job is complete. If your program is blocked, then you know the job was triggered. See the `PipelineResult` section of the [Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/) Java SDK docs for all of the available methods.

Comment: Thanks yes, I`m calling run(), I did specify the execution parameters as well. I have added more information in the question since.